# Multi guild reaction role system in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to create a reaction role system that works in multiple guilds, but i don't know how to define the interaction parameter before the button creation (i need the interaction parameter to get the guild id)
I want to define the interaction parameter before the @discord.ui.button. Is there any way i can do it?

I tried a few methods to get the interaction parameter, but none of them worked. I always got an error when running the code
Here is an example code:

````py
class Panel(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
    with open("serverinfo.json","r") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    @discord.ui.button(label=data[f"{interaction.guild.id}"]["reactionrole_1"]["menuname"],emoji=data[f"{interaction.guild.id}"]["reactionrole_1"]["emoji"],custom_id="rrbutton_1",style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def rrbutton_1(self,button:discord.Button,interaction:discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
        with open("serverinfo.json","r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        role = data[f"{interaction.guild.id}"]["reactionrole_1"]["roleid"]
        await interaction.user.add_roles(interaction.guild.get_role(role))
        await interaction.followup.send("Role has been successfully added!")```
````